# Sitemap.xml or Sitemap.html

Tags: search, seo, sitemap

I am working on one web application. I want to submit site to web crawlers using a site-map file.

There are many ways to do so

- Use sitemap.xml
- Use sitemap.html
- Use urllist.txt
- Use compressed sitemap files

All we need to do is add one of these files in root directory of applications.

My question is which option out of these is good to use ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd go with an xml sitemap as defined here http://sitemaps.org/

Html sitemaps are more geared towards user navigation and urllist.txt seems to be an old method of providing links to yahoo.

XML sitemaps in the format defined on the above site were created by Google, Yahoo! and Microsoft and are recognised by all three.

The others wont do any harm but I believe the biggest benefit will come from an xml sitemap.

As for compression, that's up to you, if you want to conserve your bandwidth then gzip it however keep in mind it must be no larger than 10mb when uncompressed.